# React Native linear gradient package does not work on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

i am trying to use this package 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient
For ios i followed these steps;
npm i --save react-native-linear-gradient
react-native link

then i restarted my packager and run react-native run-ios
App works.
Then i import the package like

```
import RNAccountKit from 'react-native-facebook-account-kit';
```

Then app fails.

Here is the issue details;
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/323

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead  of automatic installation try manual installation and try again